# The .htaccess file is not recognized

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a project made in PHP which is in a folder called Bitacora. I have this file .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When the .htaccess file is located in the root of the system ie in / var / www / html / the project runs perfectly, but when I put the .htaccess file in the folder bitacora, ie in the path / var / www / html / bitacora that is where the hosted project is located, shows me the following error

Not Found
The requested URL / admin / panel was not found on this server

It is clear that the login is visible, but when the session starts the error

What can I do to make the project work correctly by having the .htaccess file in the path / var / www / html / bitacora /  ?
Thank you !

Comment: Have you got a `<VirtualHost>` configured for this, with the *Docroot* set to */var/www/html/bitacora*?

Comment: So you're going to something like *http://bitacora.local/admin* (or whatever you've set the *ServerName* to, rather than http://127.0.0.1/bitacora/admin for instance) ... and, just to make sure, there's no existing */admin* directory (that `RewriteRule` will only trigger if there isn't)? ... though you're unlikely to 404 *with* that directory in place.

Comment: yes, my application is mounted on to Oracle VirtualBox.

I have already tried to change the apache configuration in the path /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and in the path /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

<Directory / var / www / html / bitacora />
AllowOverride All
</ Directory>

but it has not worked

Comment: I don't mean virtual server (e.g. VirtualBox) but an Apache `<VirtualHost>` directive; see: */apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf* - I suspect you've got an issue with your document root.

Comment: have you tried RewriteBase /bitacora?

Comment: lol, or that ^ ... simplest solution didn't even occur to me :D